# Do I have to setup everything again after update?

Tags: customization

I've got Blender version 2.68a and I'd like to update it, but I'm afraid that all of my setup will be deleted and I will have to set it again... Is there some way to keep all this stuff when I will be updating?

Tnaks for help.

Comment: I think, I am not sure but in the splash screen there will be an option to use the previous preferences. However I think you only get this option the first time you do this.

Comment: when you will update it, blender will ask you to load old preferences as well.
To be on safe side. Open up blender, and save the file with all the defauts/settings you made in a seperate folder. When you install new version, and some how lost your settings, load up the saved file and then make save your user settings. this will make it defaut.

Answer (score 2):

Starting at 2.52 blender started saving it's startup.blend file in a new folder for every version. When you first run a new version of blender it sees that there is no startup.blend for it and looks for the previous version then gives you an option to copy the previous settings. I think this may only look for one or two previous versions, so if you update from 2.63 to 2.70 you may not get this option.

[This manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html) describes the locations that the startup.blend can be found. You can easily find the current startup.blend (and userpref.blend) and delete it so that you will get the option to copy previous settings. You could also locate an older startup.blend file and copy that to the new version folder.

On linux, the folder is located at `~/.config/blender/`

On OSX, the folder is located at `/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Blender/`

On Windows, the folder is located at `C:\Documents and Settings\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\`