# blender 2.77a and 2.78b immediately crashes when I try to select an object

Tags: modeling

Presently using blender 2.76b (no issues at all) but try to use 2.77a or higher and it immediately crashes when I click on anything in the 3D window. On Toshiba 650c laptop with Linux 17.3

Comment: What method did you use to install?

Comment: Your graphics card may no longer be supported with the introduction of newer openGL version

Comment: Does changing the [selection method](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/system.html#opengl) help? You may need to save the startup.blend in 2.76 and manually move it for 2.78 to use  [this may help](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8570/935). Also try starting with factory settings.

Comment: thanx for all the very insightful suggestions, I shall try them and report back on results.