# Startup file erased after 3.2 update. Can I get it back?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, startup-file

I just fired up Blender and found that it had been updated. That's great and all, but it apparently erased my video sequence editor startup file. Can it be recovered, or do I have to recreate it again?

I'm not super fluent with Blender or video editing, so I'll probably have to do some digging to restore what I had. I'd rather not if I can help it.

I asked a very specific question and was given 2 links with no explanation, and then my question was closed. Neither link answered my question.

My question is, can I recover my startup file now that Blender has already updated? The links provided do not answer that question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8542/do-i-have-to-setup-everything-again-after-update https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored

Comment: So, no, I can't recover it? Sorry, but these links don't answer my question.

Comment: And now my it says my question already has answers at the 2nd of those links? No it doesn't. I asked if I can recover the file or not; that is not answered in that link.

Comment: The links should point you to the location the files are in. Whether you can recover the them or not depends on whether the files are still there or not, which only you can find out, since only  you have access to your computer

Comment: Those links are very, very old. But I'm not going to argue with you. If this is as helpful as you can be before closing someone down, then I'm in the wrong place anyway.  Thanks for nothing.

Comment: I think Duarte is being very unfair here. Just throwing a link without any explanation is really not very helpful, and kinda rude to be honest. And then closing down the question because you didn't like the response is even worse. Pretty childish.

Comment: @vegtabill, if you are using Windows, try searching the `%temp%` directory. Unfortunately, the file you have lost can be only recovered throughout the `%temp%` if you have enabled `Auto Save` in Blender before. Also, along  with your `.blend` file there is another - `.blend1`, try recovering it also. Last option I know: Open Blender, under `File` > `Recover` press `Recover Last Session`

Comment: Unless I misunderstood what you mean, the startup file is the file that determines what is shown when blender first opens. Do you perhaps mean an autosave or a recovery file?

Comment: Alexandre Marcati,  kemplerart, thank you. Just a few words that explain a little go a long way. Believe it or not, I used to be a software dev (primarily Java, backend), and I would often be asked how to do this, or if something was possible. I never, ever "helped" by just throwing links at people and shutting them down. Duarte's responses have a real RTFM feel to them, and for the record that's not a helpful attitude.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed are more recent version of Blender, then the original configuration files from previous versions will still be on your system. Each Blender version has a dedicated directory where it stores its startup file, user preferences and add-ons.

The files can be found in the following locations, as documented by [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html).

Windows:

- `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender`

Linux:

- `$HOME/.config/blender`
- `/usr/share/blender`

macOS:

- `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Blender`
- `/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.1/`

Note: By default the Steam and Windows Store version will automatically update when a new version is available. This is documented on the pages ["Installing from Steam"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/installing/steam.html) and ["Installing on Windows"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/installing/windows.html). You can avoid automatic updates by using the installer from the official website. Those versions do not automatically update.

All previous release of Blender can be found on [this page](https://download.blender.org/release/).

Comment: If you still have the previous version of Blender on your system or manually install it again, it should startup as intended when run.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. I do indeed have the Steam version now and it updated without my knowledge. I used to have the standalone version, but for some reason I switched to Steam's... I can't recall why. Thank you for this info; it is very helpful.